# What is the best way to set a fallback value in Python?

Tags: python

I've recently found myself using the following pattern a lot:

```
x = 3
if this:
   this.process()
   if this.something:
       x = this.a_value
```

I don't want to do this:

```
if this and (this.process() or True) and this.someting:
    x = this.a_value
else:
    x = 3
```

or this:

```
if this:
   this.process()
   if this.something:
       x = this.a_value
   else:
       x = 3
else:
    x = 3
```

but I can't help but feel that setting the value and then changing it is a little messy, especially considering in some use cases the fallback value is seldom used.

Is there a better/tidier way?

Comment: Does this always have the attribute a_value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think of the three options you present, the first one, i.e., the one you are using, is the best. The code is clear and everyone will know what's happening. I can't think of a neater/tidier way, this is how I would code it too, based on the *"Simple is better than complex."* principle

Re "*I can't help but feel that setting the value and then changing it is a little messy,*" if you want a default value, there's no way around setting one.

It certainly is much tidier than using the other two `else` approaches. Readability counts.

Answer (score 1):

From a code maintenance point-of-view, I'd accept the first or second case, but not the third due to the repetition.

PS: In Python I'd normally expect to see `self` for referring to the class instance object, and not `this`. Better not to use `this` for that or any other purpose, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking up bogus variable names along the lines of "this, that, another"

Comment: `(this.process() or True)` puts me off the second option. It seems silly and unclear.

Comment: @Jake: Actually I hadn't looked too closely at the logic expression of that second option. Yes I agree, that is unclear, and so I'd prefer the first option.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to not have to change a value is this:

```
processed = False
if this:
   this.process()
   if this.something:
       x = this.a_value
       processed = True
if not processed:
    x = 3
```

But then you're introducing another variable. If your default value is easily-computable, I'd just set `x` to `3` at the top. It would be understood that that is the default value. If the default value is time-consuming to compute, then I'd do the additional boolean option.

Answer (score 0):

I would have `this.proccess()` return `this` and do

```
 try: x = this.avalue if this.process() and this.something else 3
 except AttributeError: x = 3;
```

even though a naked except isnt awesome (depending on complexity of process)

[edit]second example wouldnt work so i took it out

Comment: You don't need a naked except. How does this address the `this.something` test?

Comment: fixed ;) thanks.... oh didnt account for that your right ... dang lemme think about that... ok think its fixed ... not sure havent tested it or anything

Comment: I still think the original code (first option) is clearer and easier to understand/follow (edit/update: based on *Simple is better than complex.* principle :)

Comment: yeah i think its easier to understand ... but this isn't too bad and maybe more "pythonic" (edit) _based on EAFP design principles_

Answer (score 0):

This will avoid setting the default value first, without repetition:

```
def noncefunc(default):
    if this:
       this.process()
       if this.something: return this.a_value 
    return default

x = noncefunc(3)
```

It's not especially clear, though, and certainly not an advance over what you have. If you want to do this sort of thing, you'd be better off with a language that more naturally supports functional styles by design. It would be nice if python were that language, but sadly it isn't.

Alternatively:

```
class breakexception(exception):pass
try:
   if this:
       this.process()
       if this.something: 
          x = this.a_value
          raise breakexception()
except breakexception: pass
else: x = 3
```

Again, this only sets the default if the non-default is not set first, but it isn't any easier to follow.

Finally:

```
if this:
    this.process()
    if this.something: 
       x = this.a_value
try: x = x
except UnboundLocalError: x = 3
```

This is probably the clearest of the alternatives to what you have, but it doesn't really represent much of an advance over your original form.

Stick with what you have.

Comment: Thanks for submitting some alternative ideas!